# Ruby: How modify Timezone without change time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby/Rails How to do this.

only modify the timezone of Time

```
2015-01-01 00:00:00 +0900  => 2015-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: by the way, please do not just subtract 9 hours

Answer (score -2, accepted):

take this date in variable say currentDateTime:

then use following:

```
currentDateTime.change(:offset => "+0000")
```

Comment: This doesn't work for a `Time` object. Only `DateTime`.

Comment: I think it works with a `Time` instance, although it requires a slightly different formatting of the offset value: `+04:00` for `Time` instead of `+0400` for `Datetime`.